# how to use webview v30 in android 4.3

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

All,
My webpage contains html5, it is OK on ANDROID 4.4, while something wrong on ANDROID 4.3.

After google it, I found 
[Android 4.4 update the webview](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview).

Is it possible to use new webview on ANDROID 4.3(or 4.X)?

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly.

You may like to investigate the XWalk Project[1]. However, some things to be aware of:

- it is not a drop in replacement for WebView. Some APIs are missing or work differently
- there is a significant increase (~25MB) to your APK size, and RAM size will increase too.

[1] https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: I build it and run ,but I can not find it's android-source.seems it's a web-app, can I use it in my activity?